# Python ldap3 print entries based on variable

Tags: python-3.x, function, ldap

***I am new to Python, stupid question ahead***

I need to compare the entries from a MySQL database with ldap. I created a dictionary to hold the corresponding values, when I try to loop through the dictionary and pass them to ldap3 entries to show the results it takes the variable as literal.

```
for x in values_dict:
    value2=values_dict[x]
    try:
        ldap_conn.entries[0].value2
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        print(value2)

attribute 'value2' not found
```

If I replace value2 with 'sn' or any of the other attributes I have pulled it works fine. I have also played around with exec() but this returns nothing.

```
for x in values_dict:
    value2=values_dict[x]
    test1='ldap_conn.entries[0].{}'.format(value2)
    try:
        result1=exec(test1)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        print(result1)
None
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 1 : As requested here are the values for values_dict. As stated previously the loop does parse these correctly, ldap does return the attributes, but when I try to use a variable to lookup the attributes from entries the variable is taken literally.

```
values_dict = {
        "First_Name": "givenname",
        "Middle_Name": "middlename",
        "Last_Name": "sn",
        "Preferred_Name": "extensionattribute2",
        "Work_Location": "physicaldeliveryofficename",
        "Work_City": "l",
        "Work_State": "st",
        "Work_Postal": "postalcode",
        "Work_Email": "mail"
        }
```

Comment: Could you include your values_dict and show your ldap query? Are all attributes that you defined in your values_dict queriedand returned from the LDAP server?

Comment: The LDAP query works and returns all attributes I am looking for. When I print 'value2' it prints the corrosponding value x from the loop. I will update my post when I get home.

Comment: @Moritz I have updated the OP with the dictionary values. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `somevariable.someattr`, which you are using here:

```
ldap_conn.entries[0].value2
```

Always means "access an attribute named `someattr` of `somevariable`". It's always interpreted as a literal string. If you need to dynamically access an attribute, use the `getattr` function:

```
getattr(ldap_conn.entries[0], value2)
```

You're not currently assigning that that result anywhere, so you probably want something like:

```
result1 = getattr(ldap_conn.entries[0], value2)
```

Comment: Awesome, and it's a builtin function as well. Thank you for pointing that out!